# How to specify the same type as another parameter with type annotations?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Suppose I have the following function with these type annotations:

```
import typing as _T


def foo(x: _T.List, y: _T.List) -> _T.List:
    ...
```

Now, I would like to specify the type of the items within the list, but instead of specifying the exact type I just would like to make sure that the type is the same, e.g.:

```
def foo(x: _T.List[sameType], y: _T.List[sameType]) -> _T.List[sameType]:
    ...
```

and `sameType` could be anything, as long as it is the same, or could be picked up among some types with `Union[]` but still has to be the same.

For example, the following signature:

```
def foo(x: _T.List[_T.Union[int, float]], y: _T.List[_T.Union[int, float]]) -> _T.List[_T.Union[int, float]]:
    ...
```

will not do as `mypy` will not complain about, e.g. `foo([1], [1.0])` while I would like it to warn me about this.

Comment: Are you looking for [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)?

Comment: @Axe319 Actually, yes! If you can make it into an answer, I'll accept right away.

Comment: You can accept @chepner 's answer. It's along the same lines as what I would have written. I should also mention there is a [draft PEP 695](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/) which targets Python 3.12+ that will allow you to have the same functionality without the need for an import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a type variable to make your function generic.

```
T = _T.TypeVar('T', int, float)


def foo(x: _T.List[T], y: _T.List[T]) -> _T.List[T]:
    ...
```

`T` can be bound to either `int` or `float` at runtime for each call to `foo`, but the same choice will be used for all three occurrences of `T` within the function signature.

```
foo([1], [1])  # Allowed; T ~ int
foo([1.0], [1.0]) # Allowed: T ~ float
foo([1.0], [1])  # NOT allowed; T cannot be int and float at the same time
```

Comment: I assume `'T'` can be any string. Do you also happen to have any naming convention to  suggest?

Comment: Using the same string as the variable name is the convention. I don't think anything except generated error messages cares about the string argument.